# How to get the id value of an html <li> element added to an html <ul> element using prepend() method in jQuery ?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, prepend

I would like to know How to get the id value of an html li element added to an html ul using prepend() method in jQuery. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/bootstrap.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/src/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout( test2, 500);
            $(".dropdown-menu > li").click(function(){
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
            });
        });
        function test2(){
            var subject = 1;
    $.ajax({
    url: '{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/moslem3.php')}}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {subject:subject},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data1) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data1);
                        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                            $(".dropdown-menu").prepend('<li id="'+obj[i].id+'">l\'utilisateur ayant l\'id: '+obj[i].actor+' '+obj[i].message+' l\'événement ayant l\'id: '+obj[i].object+'</li><hr>');
                        }
        }
    });
        }
    </script>
<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <input type="image"  id="notifications" alt="notifications" src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/notifications.jpg')}}"/>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click on any item of the menu (which is a Bootstrap menu) at the screenshot below nothing happens, despite It is expected that when I click on any item an alert windows appears containing the id attribute value of that item:

[image]

Although when I put the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/bootstrap.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/src/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".dropdown-menu > li").click(function(){
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
            });
        });
    </script>
<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <input type="image"  id="notifications" alt="notifications" src="{{asset('bundles/moslemtest/phptest/notifications.jpg')}}"/>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li id="1">good morning</li><hr>
            <li id="2">hello</li><hr>
            <li id="3">hi</li><hr>
            <li id="4">welcome</li><hr>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then I click on any item of the menu, an alert windows appears containing its id attribute value as you can see at the screenshot below:

[image]

It is obvious that there is a problem with the HTML li elements which are added to the HTML ul element using the prepend() method. So, my question is how can I resolve that??
I really need to use the prepend() method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegated `on` attached to the nearest non-changing ancestor of the elements:

### e.g.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This listens for 'click' bubbling up from any children of `.dropdown-menu`, *then* it applies the `li` selector, *then* it calls the supplied function for any matching element that caused the event.

The general case, if you don't have a specific ancestor, is to use `document` as the place to listen:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

*Do not use `body` as it has some weird behavior.*

Comment: I tried each one of the two codes above but it doesn't works!..I even replaced the instruction: alert($(this).attr('id')); with the instruction: alert('hello'); and it doesn't show the alert window containing the word "hello" whenever I click on an item of the menu...So could you tell me what is the issue here??..thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you have sorted this out now? If there are still problems, please post another question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation to get the info. Because those elements are not there when jQuery runs the first time, they aren't 'visible' to jQuery.

```
$('body').on('click', ".dropdown-menu > li", function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Changing your code to this invokes event delegation and captures the click evet as it bubbles up to the body, where it can then be handled properly.

Comment: Better off with `document` (or better yet, the first non-changing ancestor of the items i.e. `.dropdown-menu`). `body` has some weird behavior with delegated `click`.

Comment: I'm a fan of the first non-changing ancestor myself. I've never seen the weirdness that you mention though, only rumors. Have you witnessed it @TrueBlueAussie?

Comment: Yes, two days ago in a SO JSFiddle. It only accept clicks on child elements as if the body did not generate click events itself. Weird.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: I tried the code above but it doesn't works!..I even replaced the instruction: alert($(this).attr('id')); with the instruction: alert('hello'); and it doesn't show the alert window containing the word "hello" whenever I click on an item of the menu...So could you tell me what is the issue here??..thanks in advance.

Comment: If the code doesn't work with your changes it means that whatever you're clicking on is not `.dropdown-menu > li` or that some other issue exists. http://jsfiddle.net/xdst9/ Are there any errors in your browser's console?